# ¿Como Usar O Acceder A Un Fichero Que Se Encuentra En Google Drive?

Tags: android, google-drive

Quiero saber si es posible usar un archivo que se encuentra en la nube como si estuviera en la memoria del dispositivo estilo enlace, que este archivo que se encuentra en la nube se pueda acceder a el mediante el enlace que se creara en la memoria, pero solo abriendo o explorando el contenido de este sin tener que desencadenar ningún proceso de descarga que retrase la ejecución del archivo. Si saben si es posible lograr lo que he comentado por favor comunicármelo. Gracias

Answer (score -1):

```
 Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://www.tuenlance.com");
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
            startActivity(intent);
```

Esto te abrirá tu navegador con el enlace por defecto, espero te ayude.

**Nota:** lo puedes usar en un botón u otro control

Comment: Yo quiero crear un archivo o un acceso directo al el que se encuentra en la nube sin tener que salir del sistema de android, un ejemplo un archivo mp3 se encuentra en la nube y yo quiero lograr que se pueda ejecutar con una aplicación del sistema como un simple y ordinario reproductor.Gracias

Comment: Creo que una posibilidad es usar un Webview

Comment: Es posible ejecutar un fichero que se encuentra en la nube mediante una clase de acceso directo que crea mi aplicación utilizando un WebVIew.Gracias